# What happened to Claus in Last Exile?

Tags: last-exile, fam-the-silver-wing

Near the end of *Last Exile: Fam, the Silver Wing*, we see our former protagonist Claus...

> ...in a wheelchair.

Is there any official explanation as to why?  He's never featured in *Fam the Silver Wing*, so we don't know how this happened from that series alone.

Comment: I don't think they explain in in the anime. They most likely are doing to get you to read the *Travelers from the Hourglass* manga that runs between the original and the sequel.

Comment: I've read through that manga, and didn't see any explanation as to why the above would be the case.

Comment: It hasn't been revealed *yet*, as the manga is still ongoing.

Comment: @Krazer we should discuss this on [meta](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/303/possible-plot-related-questions-for-shows-series-that-are-ongoing-should-be-clo), no ?!

Comment: @MichelAyres:  The mini-series which focuses on the protagonists from the original series is slated to be complete in Japan, so I don't know if this would quality as one of those "the series isn't complete so we shouldn't speculate" types of questions.

Comment: ... There's a portion of one of the later episodes (can't remember which one), where he and Lavie show up for about 1 minute.  They end up getting chased and fired upon by another vanship - I simply assumed Claus was in a wheelchair from injuries he received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last Exile: Fam, the Silver Wing - Aerial Log, documents Claus in the time between Travelers from the Hourglass, and Fam, the Silver Wing. Claus sustained serious injuries in a one on one confrontation with an amnesiac Dio, when the latter arrived on Earth tracing his faint memories. While his resulting injuries have confined him to a wheelchair, Claus has forgiven the recovered, and deeply remorseful Dio. Claus' confident promise to heal and find his way back to the skies has comforted Dio. In return, this allowed Dio to find a renewed purpose to make sure the skies will be there to welcome Claus back